# Setting up custom HttpClient in RemoteAuthenticationHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I have a `RemoteAuthenticationHandler` that needs to use mTLS. For this purpose, I need to get tls certificate from my certificates store, but I don't want to create a new instance of HttpClient every time when I need to authenticate user. But problem is that if I would use `IHttpClientFactory` then I don't know how can I check if certificate in HttpClient from `IHttpClientFactory` is still valid (and if not, how to change certificate contained in HttpClient).

To validate certificate contained in HttpClient I need to get this certificate from HttpClient, but that's not possible (please correct me if I'm wrong). What's more, even if this certificate isn't valid then I can't change certificate used in concrete HttpClient.

So what can I do, if I don't want to create HttpClient every time when I need to authenticate user?

Comment: I think you [can check the certificate is valid before you create the new httpclient](https://www.meziantou.net/custom-certificate-validation-in-dotnet.htm).

Comment: The blog I provided just for reference, or you can update your post with the code, then we can know the issue clearly.

Comment: I did a logical error. If we can't modify certificate used in `HttpClient` instance, then it's valid until it expires. So when we are creating new certificate, then we just need to override current `HttpClient` instance in `IHttpClientFactory`. And there's no problem.

Comment: But what for scenario where we can't inform ASP NET Core app that certificate was changed? Besides, I don't want to validate server certificate, but certificate that I added to `HttpClientHandler` while creating `HttpClient`. (referring to your comment)